# Multiplying arrays of different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I essentially need to multiply two arrays of different sizes.

I have two datasets that can be thought of like tables of points that describe an algebraic equation. In other words, I have two arrays corresponding to x and y values for one data set and two arrays corresponding to x and y values for the other data set. The two sets of arrays are different shapes, so I can't just multiply them together.

Similar to multiplying two algebraic equations together, I need to multiply the two y-values together when they have the same x-value.

Each of these arrays are imported from .dat files.

Here are four separate ways I've tried to do it.

```py
###interpolation is an array of size 1300 defined previously
###x_vals and y_vals have same dimension that is not 1300

for i in x_vals:
    for j in y_vals:
        k = j*interpolation
print(k)

################################ attempt2 ################

# x is an array of x-values associated with interpolation
for i in x:
    for j in x_vals:
        if i==j:
            k = interpolation*y_vals
print(k)

############################### attempt3 ################

for i in x_vals:
        if x==i:
            k = interpolation*y_vals
print(k)

############################ attempt4 ################

y_vals.resize(interpolation.shape)
k = interpolation*y_vals
print(k)
```

- The **first** attempt didn't give any error messages but the result is incorrect.
- The **second** gave the following error: 
  `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'k' referenced before assignment`
- The **third** gave the following: 
  `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
- The **fourth** gave the following error message: `ValueError: resize only works on single-segment arrays`

Comment: Can you provide some input and expected output data?

Comment: Please don't make us hunt for clues... instead put the numbers in the actual code so that it becomes an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Normally when we iterate we collect the results in list (or something).  In your examples you just assign them to `k`.  The result is you only print the last assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will fix your error for attempt 2.

```
################################ attempt2 ################

###x is an array of x-values associated with interpolation
for i in x:
        for j in x_vals:
            if i==j:
                k = interpolation*y_vals
                print(k)
```